# how to align item in table row (left - center - right)

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to align items in a table row (left/center/right positions), but i could dot get it work can someone help me looking at below snippet,,,

Table Row

should align to
textview1 =  left
textview2 = center
imgview1 = right

xml for table row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/focast_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/na_msg"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/focast_day_temp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/na_msg"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/focast_day_skyIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

</TableRow>
```

myTableLayout

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/weatherforcastTable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/today_temp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >
        </TableLayout>
```

code for filling the data to table row

```
 for (Forecastday forecastday : forcastDayList) {


                        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_forcast_day_view, null);
                        TextView focast_day = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.focast_day);
                        TextView focast_day_temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.focast_day_temp);
                        ImageView  focast_day_skyIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.focast_day_skyIcon);

                        TableRow row = new TableRow(_appContext);
                        focast_day.setText(fmtDate);


                        focast_day_temp.setText(forecastday.getHigh().getCelsius() +ApplicationConstants.STRING_SPACE +ApplicationConstants.CELSIUS_DEGREES);
                        focast_day_temp.setId(count);


                        focast_day_skyIcon.setImageBitmap(forecastday.getSkyiconBitMap());


                        row.addView(view);
                        weatherforcastTable.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Could you try this : stretchColumns="0,1,2" on the TableLayout

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/weatherforcastTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/today_temp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using "layout_gravity" instead of "gravity" on the first and last columns in the xml layout for the row?  This might fix your problem by aligning forecast_day to the left of the parent table and forecast_day_skyIcon to the right.

Here's a good visualization of gravity vs. layout_gravity

http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me.

```
<TableRow 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
```

Hope it helps.