# Android spread TableLayout across page

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to make my TableLayout spread across the whole page. Right now all TableRows are "pushed" against each other. But I want them to be further apart.

Situation now:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Activity.java (added this because I'm adding TableRows dynamically)

```
public class FoundLocationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    int tableRows = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foundlocations);
        this.fillTable();
    }

    private void fillTable() {
        //Get  the tablelayout
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        //Make the columns
        String[] columns = new String[3];
        columns[0] = "Sportschool";
        columns[1] = "Afstand";
        columns[2] = "Score";

        this.addTableRow(tableLayout, columns);

        //Insert the locations hardcoded (for now).
        String[] fitar = new String[3];
        fitar[0] = "Fitar";
        fitar[1] = "12km";
        fitar[2] = "5.0";

        String[] rodea = new String[3];
        rodea[0] = "Rodea";
        rodea[1] = "6km";
        rodea[2] = "4.0";

        String[] mostreu = new String[3];
        mostreu[0] = "Mostreu";
        mostreu[1] = "30km";
        mostreu[2] = "3.0";

        addTableRow(tableLayout, fitar);
        addTableRow(tableLayout, rodea);
        addTableRow(tableLayout, mostreu);
    }

    private void addTableRow(TableLayout tableLayout, String[] text) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            TextView column = new TextView(this);
            column.setId(tableRows);
            column.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            column.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            column.setText(text[i]);
            tableRow.addView(column);
        }

        //tableRow.setLayoutParams();
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tableRows++;
    }
}
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="83dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_rood" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:text="CONFIDENTIAL"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Sportscholen die voldoen aan uw criteria:"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"></TableLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it using this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14941587/4653908

In your layout.xml add the following to the TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are confirmed about using 3 columns only, then why are you not setting the sizes in .xml file? using something like:

```
<TableRow>
<TextView>
set your size
</TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Hi Zainub, I don't see how this will solve my problem. All the text will only get bigger. But I want the margin to be bigger. Each column needs 33% of the width of the screen.

Comment: you can fix the font size as well. i guess.

Comment: But I'm not asking about that.